# Why does speed of Ball is lower in the corners of the canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

Sorry for my english it is not my native language. I hope you understand me.
I made a ball that moves in a specific path  around the canvas i define. Everything is going fine and my ball moves correctly, but i notice that when the ball reaches a corner it's speed is lower than it is when it moves straight. Does anyone Knows why this happens?
Here is my code. 
Thanks in advance!

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback) {
  return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame || function(callback) {
    window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
  };
})();

var pathArray = [];
pathArray.push({
  x: 150,
  y: 100
});
pathArray.push({
  x: 1375,
  y: 100
});
pathArray.push({
  x: 1375,
  y: 230
});
pathArray.push({
  x: 150,
  y: 230
});
pathArray.push({
  x: 150,
  y: 320
});
pathArray.push({
  x: 1375,
  y: 320
});
pathArray.push({
  x: 1375,
  y: 450
});
pathArray.push({
  x: 150,
  y: 450
});

var polypoints = makePolyPoints(pathArray);
var width = 15;
var height = 30;
var speed = 1 / 2;
var position = 0;

animate();

function animate() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    requestAnimFrame(animate);
    position += speed;
    if (position > polypoints.length - 1) {
      return;
    }
    var pt = polypoints[position];
    if (pt) {
      ctx.save();
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.translate(pt.x, pt.y);
      ctx.arc(-width / 2, -height / 2, 12, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      ctx.fillStyle = "#B22222";
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.restore();
    }
  }, 1000 / 60);
}

function makePolyPoints(pathArray) {

  var points = [];
  for (var i = 1; i < pathArray.length; i++) {
    var startPt = pathArray[i - 1];
    var endPt = pathArray[i];
    var dx = endPt.x - startPt.x;
    var dy = endPt.y - startPt.y;
    for (var n = 0; n <= 200; n++) {
      var x = startPt.x + dx * n / 200;
      var y = startPt.y + dy * n / 200;
      points.push({
        x: x,
        y: y
      });
    }
  }
  return (points);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1515" height="950" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```

Comment: Seems like you are always using **200 steps**, both to cover the rather big horizontal distances and to cover the much smaller vertical distances.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because when your `makePolyPoints()` function splits the path into points, it always creates 200 points per line, not taking the actual distance into account.

What you wanna do is calculate the distance using pythagoras, and then set the number of points accordingly. I included a `speedFactor` into the function parameters, so you can fine tune.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback) {
  return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame || function(callback) {
    window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
  };
})();

var pathArray = [];
pathArray.push({
  x: 150,
  y: 100
});
pathArray.push({
  x: 1375,
  y: 100
});
pathArray.push({
  x: 1375,
  y: 230
});
pathArray.push({
  x: 150,
  y: 230
});
pathArray.push({
  x: 150,
  y: 320
});
pathArray.push({
  x: 1375,
  y: 320
});
pathArray.push({
  x: 1375,
  y: 450
});
pathArray.push({
  x: 150,
  y: 450
});

var polypoints = makePolyPoints(pathArray, 5);
var width = 15;
var height = 30;
var speed = 1 / 2;
var position = 0;

animate();

function animate() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    requestAnimFrame(animate);
    position += speed;
    if (position > polypoints.length - 1) {
      return;
    }
    var pt = polypoints[position];
    if (pt) {
      ctx.save();
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.translate(pt.x, pt.y);
      ctx.arc(-width / 2, -height / 2, 12, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      ctx.fillStyle = "#B22222";
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.restore();
    }
  }, 1000 / 60);
}

function makePolyPoints(pathArray, speedFactor) {

  var points = [];
  for (var i = 1; i < pathArray.length; i++) {
    var startPt = pathArray[i - 1];
    var endPt = pathArray[i];
    var dx = endPt.x - startPt.x;
    var dy = endPt.y - startPt.y;
    var distance = Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy)
    var steps = distance/speedFactor
    for (var n = 0; n <= steps; n++) {
      var x = startPt.x + dx * n / steps;
      var y = startPt.y + dy * n / steps;
      points.push({
        x: x,
        y: y
      });
    }
  }
  return (points);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1515" height="950" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time an your answer!! That was very helpful. :)